# Storage data (localstroage, IndexedDb) gets deleted whenever the application restarts in dev mode (electron-webpack)

Tags: webpack, electron

This relates to [electron-webpack](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack).

Storage data (localstroage, IndexedDb) is getting deleted on app restarts. Meaning, if I completely stop the build, and start again. The data is maintained if the app simply restarts because of HMR or anything else that doesn't stop the dev build.

I have no idea how or where to start looking. I was not able to reproduce this in electron-starters that don't use electron-webpack. I was able to reproduce it easily by using [electron-webpack-quick-start](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start) and only in dev mode. Running the packaged app doesn't face this problem. So I'm guessing this must be related to `electron-webpack dev`.

[I opened this issue on github but it doesn't seem very active.](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/issues/240)

Comment: you need to provide a minimal code example with the problem.

Comment: As I stated, electron-webpack-quick-start repo shows the same problem. If I store something in localstorage, then restart the app completely, it'll be gone.

Comment: You should `Help others reproduce the problem`
Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on `http://sqlfiddle.com/` or `http://jsbin.com/`) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.